# Save Dictionary with multiple items to excel file with multiple sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

[image: 206 Keys in my dictionary]

I have a dictionary with 206 items with keys as shown in the image. Each value in the key is a data frame with 26 rows and 4 columns. I want to store each item of my dictionary as one sheet in an excel file. So I need an excel file with 206 sheets in it.

```
voltage = {}
for sheet in input.sheet_names:
voltage[sheet] = pd.read_excel(input, sheet)

for sheet in voltage:
l = ( round((len(voltage[sheet]))/25) )
voltage[sheet]['DT'] = l
voltage[sheet] = voltage[sheet][0::l]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excelfromcode.xlsx')
for sheet in voltage:
voltage[sheet].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet[5:1035:5])
writer.save()
```

I tried this ( last 4 lines correspond to converting the dictionary into an excel file). But only the 1st sheet is being saved into the excel file. It is not iterating and saving all the 206 files. Please let me know what changes I need to make to the code.

Note** 'Writer.save' is written outside the 'for' loop

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is

```
writer=pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") 
for key in volt:
    volt[key].to_excel(writer,sheet_name=key)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

?

Comment: Yes. I actually figured out the problem after posting the question :) My sheet names were given wrongly. Anyways, thank you for responding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excelfromcode.xlsx')
for sheet in voltage:
voltage[sheet].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet[:206], index=False)

writer.save()
```

I just changed the sheet_names from sheet[5:1035:5] ---> sheet[0:206]. As it already knows the sheet names(5,10,15,20....1035), we just need to give the number of sheets(0 to 206) instead of trying to name them again.